# Вывод данных со слайдера jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, jquery-ui

Как в jquery/jquery-ui сделать вывод данных со слайдера в одно значение после запятой? То есть строка `value: [1000, 50000]` задает эти значения слайдеру, но проблема в том что они так и выводятся, подскажите есть ли возможность установить вывод в таком формате - `1,1 2,5`тоесть чтобы цыфра до запятой это тысячи/тысячные а после сто/сотые как это можно вывести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

задайте [step](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-step) = .001, value: [1,50]

```js
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  step:.001,
  range: true,
  min: 1,
  max: 50,
  values: [ 3, 5 ],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.values);
  }

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

**UP:**

от 1000 до 1000000 => двузначное число:

```js
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  min: 3,
  max: 6,
  step:.1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
      console.log('число', Math.round(10**ui.value)); 
      console.log('запись в два знака', ui.value);
  }
});
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <div id="slider"></div>
```

**UP2**Линейное отображение (в отличие от перыдущего - точное и захватывает больше вариантов)

```js
const max = 9.9;
// y = a*x + b;
// x = 0, y = 1000 => 
const b = 1e3;
// x = 9.9, y = 1000000, a = (y-b)/x =>
const a = (1e6-b)/max; //100909.09090909091, можно округлить вниз для удобства использования. но тогда до миллиона не дотянетесь немного
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  min: 0,
  max: max,
  step: .1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
      console.log('число', a*ui.value+b); 
      console.log('запись в два знака', ui.value);
  }
});
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Да могли бы и не приводить пример кода)) В таком случае как тогда посоветуете реализовать диапазон от 1000 до 1000000 чтобы на выходе получалось двузначное число?

Comment: Это как? 1000 и 1000000 не двузачные числа...

Comment: Получается значения до 1000 будут выводится (0.1, 0.5 и т.д.) свыше 1000 (1.2, 1.6 и т.д.) а вот милионные хз как выводить((

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev обновил ответ, посмотрите, есть такой вариант. хранить не само число, а степень 10 - умещается в два знака, правда с потерей точности

Comment: Интересный вариант, в любом случае вы очень помогли, благодарю.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev добавил еще один вариант, получше)